# Terminology for beam drill?

Tags: hand-tools

[image]
This is called a Beam Drill in the USA, but I would like to know the terminology for this in British English. I'm trying to find one locally to me (on ebay) in the UK and failing completely...

So my question is what other names are these known by?

Comment: A quick Google search instantly brought up "beam boring machine" as another (common) reference to these.

Comment: "beam auger" is also going to be used by many on both sides of the Atlantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are also known by "beam boring machine" and "beam auger".